# Ranorex - Can't invoke java method WITHOUT parameters but WITH return value

Tags: java, c#, automation, overloading, ranorex

I'm trying to test Java app with Ranorex.

Inside `Ranorex.JavaElement` class I have two methods:

```
public virtual void InvokeMethod(string name);
public object InvokeMethod(string methodName, params object[] args);
```

This overloading doesn't allow to invoke method without parameters, but with return value, because the overloading mechanism doesn't take in considerations the return value, so when I'm calling a method without parameters it always chooses the first option.

Is there any other way in Ranorex to invoke a Java method without parameters but with return value?

Thanks

Comment: you can call the second method and pass an empty args array

Comment: @wero I already tried to pass null or empty array of Object for the "params" variable, I'm getting "ActionFailedException".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the following code worked for me.

```
 Object[] param = new Object[0];     
 JavaElement myElement =  repo.Java.Self.As<JavaElement>();
 var returnVal = myElement.InvokeMethod("myMethodToInvoke", param);
```